# Algorithm to randomly and uniformly tile a grid with different sizes

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d

Assume an N x M grid. Into this I need to randomly lay out tiles which are sized from 1x1 to I X J grid units. The key problem is to find a way to use each different size around the same number of times and be fairly randomly distributed.

As an example, imagine a floor that's 10 x 20 square feet, You have stacks of 1x1, 1x2 and 2x2 tiles which you want to layout the floor with and you want the design to be random looking and use around the same count of each tile.

You could also think of the problem in reverse, cutting up a floor into pieces of these sizes.

I've seen tree map algorithms but they don't quite match the requirement. If you restrict the pieces to 1 x I then the problem is 1 dimensional and easy. It's the 2D version that seems more difficult. Any ideas or pointers is helpful.

Relaxing the need to be (1) random or (2) similar does make it easier but both are important. I have some ideas on doing it but nothing feels right yet.

Comment: Please show us your current ideas and why they don't work

Comment: What does the word **uniformly** mean in this context?

Comment: Wow! You asked 24 questions and voted only once! Congratulations! That is surely a record!

Comment: No it isn't homework, it's a real question.

Answer (score 0):

An alterative solution is to randomly sort your tiles and use a spatial index to fill the grid. The idea is that a spatial index subdivide the grid into 2 dimension so you can check for quads. Otherwise you want to use a DFS to find the optimal solution.